# Using static images with sorl-thumbnail

Tags: django, sorl-thumbnail

I am trying to serve the thumbnail of a file that resides in my STATIC_ROOT folder. It doesn't really matter if it ends up in MEDIA_URL/cache, but sorl-thumbnail will not load the image from the static folder.

current code:

```
{% thumbnail "images/store/no_image.png" "125x125" as thumb %}
```

hack that works

```
{% thumbnail "http://localhost/my_project/static/images/store/no_image.png" "125x125" as thumb %}
```

I don't like the hack because
A) It is not dry (my project is actually served from a sub-directory of /
B) It is using http to grab a file that is only 3 directories away, seems pointlessly inefficient

Comment: Mikko Hellsing (sorl-thumbnail developer) said I needed to instatiate sorl-thumbnail with a base_url, but I have not been able to find any documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Django 1.3 you should take a look at the docs about [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

If you setup everything correctly, you can include your images like this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/store/no_image.png" />
```

Comment: That's what I normally use, but I need to re-size it somewhat arbitrarily (thus the use of sorl-thumbnail). If it turns out to not be possible to use sorl-thumbnail for static content, I may be forced to create multiple resolutions of the file.

Comment: @DarwinSurvivor- Have you found the answer to this question? I too am trying to create thumbnails of static files but can't figure it out.

Comment: At least with easy_thumbnails this shouldn't be a problem at all: http://packages.python.org/easy-thumbnails/usage.html#non-django-file-objects

Answer (score 4):

I worked around this by passing through a file to the template context from my view.

Here is an example util function I called from my views:

```
def get_placeholder_image():
    from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
    from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
    storage_class = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)
    storage = storage_class()
    placeholder = storage.open(settings.PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_PATH)
    image = ImageFile(placeholder)
    image.storage = storage
    return image
```

You could probably do something similar as a custom template tag.

Answer (score 3):

Template filter works. But I am not sure, whether there is each time reading from storage. If so, it is unreasonably...

```
from django.template import Library
from django.core.files.images import ImageFile
from django.core.files.storage import get_storage_class
register = Library()

@register.filter
def static_image(path):
    """
    {% thumbnail "/img/default_avatar.png"|static_image "50x50" as img %}
        <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{img}}"/>
    {% endthumbnail %}
    """
    storage_class = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)
    storage = storage_class()
    image = ImageFile(storage.open(path))
    image.storage = storage
    return image
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hijacking the fact that it can get from a URL, and wrote my own tag that overrides the _render method on the ThumbnailNode:

```python
from django.template import Library

from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.contrib.sites.models import get_current_site


from sorl.thumbnail.templatetags.thumbnail import ThumbnailNode as SorlNode
from sorl.thumbnail.conf import settings
from sorl.thumbnail.images import DummyImageFile
from sorl.thumbnail import default

register = Library()


class ThumbnailNode(SorlNode):
    """allows to add site url prefix"""

    def _render(self, context):
        file_ = self.file_.resolve(context)
        if isinstance(file_, basestring):
            site = get_current_site(context['request'])
            file_ = "http://" + site.domain + file_

        geometry = self.geometry.resolve(context)
        options = {}
        for key, expr in self.options:
            noresolve = {u'True': True, u'False': False, u'None': None}
            value = noresolve.get(unicode(expr), expr.resolve(context))
            if key == 'options':
                options.update(value)
            else:
                options[key] = value
        if settings.THUMBNAIL_DUMMY:
            thumbnail = DummyImageFile(geometry)
        elif file_:
            thumbnail = default.backend.get_thumbnail(
                file_, geometry, **options
                )
        else:
            return self.nodelist_empty.render(context)
        context.push()
        context[self.as_var] = thumbnail
        output = self.nodelist_file.render(context)
        context.pop()
        return output


@register.tag
def thumbnail(parser, token):
    return ThumbnailNode(parser, token)
```

Then from the template:

```
{% with path=STATIC_URL|add:"/path/to/static/image.png" %}
{% thumbnail path "50x50" as thumb %}
<img src="{{ thumb.url }}" />
...
```

Not the neatest solution... :-/

Answer (score 0):

The default value of setting sorl THUMBNAIL_STORAGE is the same settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE.

You must create storage that uses STATIC_ROOT, for example you can use **'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'** and instantiate with **location=settings.STATIC_ROOT** and **base_url=settings.STATIC_URL**

Only THUMBNAIL_STORAGE set in settings for a 'MyCustomFileStorage' did not work. So I had to do to DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE and it worked.

Define in settings.py:

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'utils.storage.StaticFilesStorage'

utils/storage.py:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


def check_settings():
    """
    Checks if the MEDIA_(ROOT|URL) and STATIC_(ROOT|URL)
    settings have the same value.
    """
    if settings.MEDIA_URL == settings.STATIC_URL:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The MEDIA_URL and STATIC_URL "
                                   "settings must have different values")
    if (settings.MEDIA_ROOT == settings.STATIC_ROOT):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT "
                                   "settings must have different values")




class TimeAwareFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):
    def accessed_time(self, name):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getatime(self.path(name)))

    def created_time(self, name):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(self.path(name)))

    def modified_time(self, name):
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(self.path(name)))



class StaticFilesStorage(TimeAwareFileSystemStorage):
    """
    Standard file system storage for static files.

    The defaults for ``location`` and ``base_url`` are
    ``STATIC_ROOT`` and ``STATIC_URL``.
    """
    def __init__(self, location=None, base_url=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if location is None:
            location = settings.STATIC_ROOT
        if base_url is None:
            base_url = settings.STATIC_URL
        if not location:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
                                       "without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting. Set it to "
                                       "the absolute path of the directory that holds static files.")
            # check for None since we might use a root URL (``/``)
        if base_url is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
                                       "without having set the STATIC_URL setting. Set it to "
                                       "URL that handles the files served from STATIC_ROOT.")
        if settings.DEBUG:
            check_settings()
        super(StaticFilesStorage, self).__init__(location, base_url, *args, **kwargs)
```

Reference:

https://github.com/mneuhaus/heinzel/blob/master/staticfiles/storage.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#default-file-storage